# Sharing / transforming appsettings across projects and environments

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, web-deployment

I got a Visual Studio solutions with multiple projects (function apps and a web API) and a datalayer that is shared between all the projects. I've set up the solution so all projects share the same config (`appsettings.json`) based on this article: https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/

All projects are based on .net core.

I've set up a build and a release pipeline for the dev environment. But I need a Test and production environment. How do I transform the shared config before releasing it to the test and production environment?

Answer (score 2):

You don't. That's not how configuration works in ASP.NET Core. Configuration is *overridden*, not *transformed*. There's an order of ops to how the different configuration sources are applied, which is basically the order in which they're registered. The default is JSON < Environment-specific JSON < User Secrets < Environment Variables < Command-line Arguments.

If you need configuration to vary by environment, you're going to rely on the environment-specific JSON files (for general config) or environment variables and/or something like Azure Key Vault (for secrets). Since all of these come later in the configuration registration, any value you set there will override the values in your `appsettings.json`.

For things like environment-specific JSON, which is loaded is dependent on the value of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`, which can be set as an environment variable or passed as a command-line argument `--environment`. In either case, the value set corresponds to the `{environment}` portion of `appsettings.{environment}.json`. In other words, if you set the environment as `Production`, then `appsettings.Production.json` will be loaded into the config, if it is present. Environment variables are tied to the environment itself so are not dependent on any particular environment value.

Comment: So I'll need to have appsettings for each environments in each of my projects? I'm trying to avoid having to duplicate appsettings.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, but having separate apps sharing common settings begins to beg the question of whether those should be separate apps at all.

Comment: All the function apps are seperate projects + the web api they all rely on some repositories. So the apps need to have connection string etc present once it's deployed.

Comment: See that's a perfect example. If the apps all need the same connection string, then you have not properly abstracted your data dependency and/or you're not truly subdividing your domain. In other words, you still have a monolithic app, just broken into separate projects.

Comment: There are definitely use cases for sharing configuration across multiple domains. Your system might want to share a common logging configuration, SQL Server connection string, Redis backplane, Azure Service Bus, etc.  This does not violate design principles in any way. There is even entire solutions built around that concept in Azure called Azure App Configuration